# How to reload page once using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I reload a page once on page load (an equivalent to pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>)

```
$( window ).load(function() {   
    window.location.reload(true); 
});
```

This loops itself.
How can I make it happen only once?

Comment: You'll likely want to tell us why you're reloading the page, as is, this appears to be a poor practice.

Comment: One option is to set a cookie.  Another is to add a flag to the URL instead of doing a simple reload.  But the bigger question is why do this?

Comment: since i did not find a simple way of updating the cookies on navigator back button click, this would do the trick

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will do it:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) {
     window.location.replace(window.location.href+'?reload');
}
```

With your jQuery-Code:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) {
         window.location.replace(window.location.href+'?reload');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Nowadays... HTML5 provides localStorage:

```
/* if my "reload" var isn't set locally.. getItem will be false */
if (!localStorage.getItem("reload")) {
    /* set reload to true and then reload the page */
    localStorage.setItem("reload", "true");
    location.reload();
}
/* after reloading remove "reload" from localStorage */
else {
    localStorage.removeItem("reload");
    // localStorage.clear(); // or clear it, instead
}
```

---

and this doesn't need jquery. Hope it helps, as it helped me.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me i was facing this issue from past couple of days and was worried whether it will solve or not and tried all the above solution but nothing works than i tried your code and it worked thanks very much :)

Comment: **For me this is better**. In the first two answer think this: The url changed and it reload for the first time, if the user visit other pages and do backward in the browser your page *won't* reload. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check if the current URL contains '#'
    if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1)
    {
    // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
    url = document.URL+"#";
    location = "#";

    //Reload the page
    location.reload(true);

    }
    });
</script>
```

Due to the if condition the page will reload only once.I faced this problem too and when I search ,I found a nice solution.
This works for me fine.And thanks for http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?267853-Auto-refresh-page-once-only-after-first-load

Answer (score 2):

Add below line into your HTML file:

```
    `<input name="refreshed" value="no" id="refreshed" />`<input name="refreshed" value="no" id="refreshed" />
```

And call this function on onload of page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function() {
    if ($("#refreshed").val() == "no") {
        location.reload();
        $("#refreshed").val("yes"); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload page with some query string for reference.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


$(window).load(function() {   

   if(getParameterByName('reloaded')){
      //loaded once
   }else{
      window.location = window.location.href+'?reloaded=true';
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>location.replace('http://url.goes.here');</script>");
```

repeats once

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help meanwhile i have made it working this way

```
   function SetCookie (name, value) {
    var argv=SetCookie.arguments;
    var argc=SetCookie.arguments.length;
    var expires=(argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
    var path=(argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
    var domain=(argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
    var secure=(argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
    document.cookie=name+"="+escape(value)+
        ((expires==null) ? "" : ("; expires="+expires.toGMTString()))+
        ((path==null) ? "" : ("; path="+path))+
        ((domain==null) ? "" : ("; domain="+domain))+
        ((secure==true) ? "; secure" : "");
}



    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
        {
            c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        }
        if (c_start == -1)
        {
            c_value = null;
        }
        else
        {
            c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
            var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1)
            {
                c_end = c_value.length;
            }
            c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
    }   




if (getCookie('first_load'))        
    {
        if (getCookie('first_load')==true)
        {
            window.location.reload(true); // force refresh page-liste
            SetCookie("first_load",false);
        }
    }
    SetCookie("first_load",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way (worked in my case)

If you are using jQuery, set an global variable in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var only_once = "0";
</script>
```

Then use this JS code in your jQuery page (inside `<div data-role="page" id="myPage">`)

```
<script>

        $('#myPage').bind('pageshow', function() { 
            if (only_once==1) {
                only_once = 0 ;
                location.reload();

            } 
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved a similar problem with github static pages.
I wanted to force reload of pages (ie no caching) since the caching was causing broken links.

The trouble with that was I could not use meta http-equiv OR htaccess to change caching since github overrides these settings.

None of the "reload only once" solutions would work across the back button.

The following seems to work on all browsers:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return window.location.reload(true)">
```

This forces a reload directly from the server whenever the user *leaves* a page (same effect as no caching).  The dreaded loop is avoided.